# Was there an orange in “Elephant’s Dream”?

Tags: elephants-dream

There is a tradition of naming each of the Open Projects from the Blender Foundation after fruits, and having the fruits appear somewhere in the corresponding animated short films.

However, I could not find an orange in their first film *Elephant’s Dream*, aka “Project Orange”.

Was there an orange in it or did they start the tradition of putting the fruits in the movies after that?